# Template Error after pushing to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Ruby: 2**
**Rails: 4**

I have recently setup a belongs_to on my `orders` model. I changed what used to be a field called `location` to `location_id` and changed its type from `string` to `integer`. Everything works fantastic in my local environment, but after pushing to heroku - I receive this error when attempting to access `orders/new`:

```
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `location_id' for #<Order:0x007f034232d858>):
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/orders/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_orders_new_html_erb___1199879637359872052_69825989547780'
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <%= f.label :location_id %><br>
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="field">
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415722+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/orders/_form.html.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_orders__form_html_erb___1716646795441888489_69825989572420'
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415722+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <div class="field">
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <%= f.select :location_id, @locations, prompt: "Select One" %>
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415564+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:   </div>
2013-12-06T21:26:51.415722+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   </div>
```

Everything works locally, but for the sake of completeness, here is a little extra:

**2 excerpts from orders_controller**

```
def new
    @locations = Location.all.collect { |l| [l.name, l.id]}
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, :notes, :email, :location_id)
end
```

**From the form partial in question:**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :location_id, @locations, prompt: "Select One" %>
</div>
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Seems to be a problem with migrations..

Answer (score 0):

did you run your migration?

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```